# Как послать заглавную букву в неактивное окно?

Tags: c#, winforms

Пытаюсь отправить строку в неактивное окно, но даже если строка содержит заглавные буквы, отправляется все равно строчная. Вот код отправки:

```
PostMessage(hWnd, 0x0100, (IntPtr)((int)Keys.A), (IntPtr)0);
PostMessage(hWnd, 0x0101, (IntPtr)((int)Keys.A), (IntPtr)0);
```

Также пробовал `Keys.A | Keys.ShiftKey` - не помогает.

Comment: Что вы жмете на клаве, чтобы большую букву получить? Вот и здесь то же самое, такой же порядок нажатия и отпускания клавиш.

Comment: Напишите свой обработчик цикла сообщений (Message Loop), понажимайте на клаве то что вам нужно, смотрите, что прилетает от системы. Действуйте по образу и подобию.

Comment: [`SendKeys`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys?view=net-5.0) не пробовали?

Comment: @aepot, вместо своего обработчика Message Loop удобнее использовать Spy++, она даже в меню Tools в Visual Studio есть.

Comment: @VladD sendKeys не работает в фоне

Comment: @inibyl: А, точно, вы шлёте неактивному окну.

Comment: Эта задача нерешаема. Неактивное приложение на то и неактивное, что оно не может принимать ввод. Смотреть на Message Loop можно хоть до посинения, но если программа считывает состояние Shift напрямую с клавиатуры (напр. GetAsyncKeyState), то единственный способ подсунуть ей большую букву - нажать этот Shift на клавиатуре.